# R code for system.time() user time extraction

Tags: r

I need to run system.time loop for factorial function for numbers 1:N and store the result as dataframe with 2 columns number and user time in order to monitor the performance of factorial function implementation using recursion as well as loop.
I was able to run system.time() in using for loop but could not extract just the value of user.self.

for example

`i<-system.time(fact(1000))`

which gives me output something as

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.006   0.000   0.006
```

However , I just want to extract numerical value 0.006 and put it as a column value in my dataframe with the corresponding number N ( in this case 1000) .

Further extracting gives me user data along with the string "user.self" but I want just 0.006.

```
> i[1]
user.self 
    0.006
```

The dataframe will ultimately look somewhat like below

```
   N      recursiveTime  loopTime
1  1000   0.06            0.003
2  1100   0.06            0.004    
3  1200   0.07            0.004
```

Comment: What is `loopTime` column?

Comment: Needed to implement factorial function using 1.recursion and 2.For loop.
first column "recursiveTime" will store the user time extracted from system.time() when factorial was calculated using recursion and second column "loopTime" will store the user time extracted from system.time()  when factorial was calculated using for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the double brackets.

```
i[["elapsed"]]
```

Or

`i[["user.self"]]` if that's what you want, which one are you after?

Or, take the name off the value:

```
avalue<-i[i]#your example with the name attached
names(avalue)=NULL; #now avalue is just a number again.
```